# PosgreSQL trigger function update after insert

Tags: postgresql, database-trigger

I am new at PosgreSQL triggers. Based on documentation I was trying to make trigger function, but it's not working and don't udnertand why.
There is a scraping which insert into my DB records of realestates. I want to make update of new inserted records based on selected conditions. 
Here is my code for trigger function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION czynsz_clear() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $body$ 
    BEGIN
            IF administrative_fees IS NOT NULL 
                AND administrative_fees_m2 IS NULL 
                AND area IS NOT NULL
                AND type_id IN (6,1)
                AND administrative_fees > 1 AND area > 1
            THEN    
            UPDATE realestates_realestate SET administrative_fees_m2 = TRUNC((administrative_fees/ AREA):: INTEGER,2)
            RETURN NEW;
            END IF;
    END;
$body$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

So logic is that:
After insert into DB realestates_realestate a new record, I want to check does selected fields are null or other condition, then make an update.
After creating the function, I wanted to make a trigger launch this function after Insert into table.

What I am doing wrong? I am using HeidiSQL (10.3.0.5771) and appears message:

> ERROR: syntax error at near RETURN. Line 11: RETURN NEW;

After deleted this RETURN NEW, appears error END IF; and the same message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to change the row that was just inserted, don't use `UPDATE` assign the value to the field or the new record.

To access the column values, use the `new` record as well.

Something like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION czynsz_clear() 
  RETURNS TRIGGER 
AS $body$ 
BEGIN
  if new.administrative_fees IS NOT NULL 
     AND new.administrative_fees_m2 IS NULL 
     AND new.area IS NOT NULL
     AND new.type_id IN (6,1)
     AND new.administrative_fees > 1 
     AND new.area > 1
  THEN    
    new.administrative_fees_m2 := TRUNC((administrative_fees/ AREA)::INTEGER,2);
  END IF;

  RETURN NEW; -- this needs to be outside of the IF
END;
$body$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

This assumes the trigger is defined as a row level trigger, e.g.

You also need to make it a BEFORE trigger

```
create trigger ..
  BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE on ....
  FOR EACH ROW execute procedure czynsz_clear();
```

---

The error you got was caused by the fact that your UPDATE statement was not ended with a `;`. But even after fixing that, you would have gotten errors, because the column names (in the `IF` part) can't be referenced like that.

And finally the trigger would have only worked in case the `IF` conditions were true, because otherwise the trigger would not return anything. So the `return new;` needs to be outside the `IF` statement.

Comment: Thank you a lot! It works, also needed to add DELIMITER $$ on top. I've created trigger:

create TRIGGER clear_czynsz_trigger AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON realestates_realestate
  FOR EACH ROW execute procedure czynsz_clear();

And logically, it should works on any update done at my row. I've made an update on another column for this row just to check does it works and didn't update me row for administrative_fees_m2. Why? Should I make Before Insert or Update?

Comment: Yes, if you want to change the row, you have to use a `BEFORE` trigger. No idea what you mean with `DELIMITER $$` that is not a standard Postgres command

Comment: When I was trying to use the code exact as was above, appeared error: 'ERROR:  unterminated dollar-quoted string at or near "$body$ BEGIN'. I saw someone already asked about this problem and adding this works.

Comment: that must be something specific to your SQL client.

Comment: Yes, it's Heidi :( 
thanks a lot again. and it works, I've checked, when I replace "after" to "before" for update it works. I also specified which columns to apply for update, so won't be launched on avery update of all columns just specified. 
Now I am just thinking, could I move all conditions from function to trigger using condition when? And in that case should I use:
-- WHEN OLD.administrative_fees_m2 is NULL or WHEN new.administrative_fees_m2 is NULL?

Comment: @Michał: yes, you can move the condition to the trigger definition. And you are right, that would make things faster in those cases where the conditions are not met.